# MYSQL Date - str_to_date() function messed with year in my dates

Tags: mysql, datetime

Just changed the date from the format dd-mm-yy using str_to_date() function in MYSQL.
The column date had the date in dd-mm-yyyy format. I used following query :

```
UPDATE invoice SET date=str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

and dates got converted to correct format yyyy-mm-dd but all years in my date column got changed to 2020.

Now I have two questions :

1] How can I change all 2020 year to 2011 in my date

2] What do you think, why did this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
UPDATE table SET datefield=datefield - INTERVAL 9 year WHERE records you want to change
```

If you leave out the `WHERE` clause it changes **ALL** records in the table.